# trying to export db to SDCARD

Tags: android, export

I'm pretty new to android and I'm trying to export my DB to the SDCARD so I can import it into my other application.

Any suggestions?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Could you detail why exactly you want this, if this exchange should go in both directions, etc. -- this sounds like you might want shared userId or a ContentProvider.

Comment: I have one application that is a free version.  Then I made one that has some nice upgrades.  But I want the users to be able to export their current database to the SDCARD and then import to the paid version.

Comment: Have you searched SO for the more general problem of [implementing free/paid Android applications](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+%2Bfree+%2Bpaid)? There's some good answers there, from shared user ID to having a free app and an paid "unlock" application with no need for duplicating your whole app.

Answer (score 1):

Export example:

```
public void exportDB(){
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "data/data/com.mypack.myapp/databases/mydb.db";
            String backupDBPath = sd + "/filename.db";
            File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Import is very similar to export:

```
public void importDB(){
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = sd + "/filename.db";
            String backupDBPath = "data/data/com.mypack.myapp/databases/mydb_2.db";
            File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not be the best solution for what you are trying to do, your database is already stored in /data/data/your.package.name. You just need to load it as a file and save to SD card. Check here for the the code that does this:

http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7749

Comment: Ok, in that case how would I import from one local DB to another?  Instead of exporting to SDCARD and then importing back again.

Comment: You could could create a Content Provider in the free application  that would expose whole database to other applications. Then on the first run of the paid app, create a new empty database, get the data from the original app by querying the Content Provider and fill in the new database.