# Nexus 7 sqlite folder /data/ permission denied

Tags: android, sqlite

HI I am developing an android application for android on nexus 7 device. 
I am trying to copy my `database.db` from assets to `/data/data/myPackage/databases/` folder. Nothing wrong till here. No exceptions and everything runs smoothly.

But When i try to get into /data/data/ folder through adb shell or with file explorer it says permission denied or just doesnt show anything.

Am I missing something here ?

PS: myPackage is just symbolic i have my own package name in its stead

> Command line is here

```
 shell@tilapia:/ $ cd /data/                                                    
 shell@tilapia:/data $ ls 
 opendir failed, Permission denied
```

Comment: you need to be rooted to access the data folder

Comment: ok. Then how can i see whats happening inside my db other than Emulator ?

Comment: you can programatically export your database to the sdcard but other than that you cant access it without gaining root

Comment: Okay. I could be wrong but, I believe it had not been like this since always. Do you know at which API level was this introduced.

Comment: you always needed root to get to the data folder

Comment: Ok. Thanks for keeping me sane. :)

Comment: As long as the application is built in DEBUG mode, you can use the run-as command. This gives you the same access rights as the application without need to be rooted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have your device rooted to be able to access that folder.

If you want to look at your database you can always export it to the sdcard and look at it there.

see this link for an example on how to do that

[trying to export db to SDCARD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300044/trying-to-export-db-to-sdcard/7300247#7300247)

Answer (score 1):

you can always get the db out of the emulator, but never from a live device or else it would be easy to write apps that read/write other apps' databases and create malware